# Is it possible for a parent page to interact with an embedded iFrame?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iframe

I am writing a new ASP.NET/MVC system for a customer who has a 3rd party provider for a certain service.  The 3rd party provides a simple web interface for the customer to upload and maintain data.

Now the customer wants us to build this interface to the 3rd party into our system, since some of the data they're sending to the 3rd party is being pulled from our database.

Easiest, quick & dirty, would be to make an iFrame to the 3rd party site.  But will that give us the desired functionality?  Is there a way to push data into the iFrame from our system?  Can we pull the response from the iFrame into our system?  Is it possible to apply our own stylesheet on top of the iFrame so that the system doesn't look like Dr Frankenstein's monster, cobbled together from different looking components?

Or do we have to design our own UI that exactly mimicks the 3rd party UI, posting to the 3rd party URL and parsing the response so that it can be presented in an appropriate way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or do we have to design our own UI that exactly mimicks the 3rd party
>   UI, posting to the 3rd party URL and parsing the response so that it
>   can be presented in an appropriate way?

I am afraid that this might be the way to go if the 3rd party service doesn't provide you with an API or a way to customize the CSS stylesheets (in which case you could have used an `iframe` passing some parameter that would change the CSS).

Comment: +1 Thanks.  Actually they do provide an API.  But the customer wanted to save on development costs by just plugging in to the existing interface... guess that won't work.